# Cannot invoke method list on null object

Tags: grails

I am trying to follow the ajax - driven select tutorial here: http://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP however, I get the following error:

```
URI
    /ajaxSelects/
Class
    java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
    Cannot invoke method list() on null object
```

I followed the tutorial exactly. The problem seems to be from the following code, where grails does not like Country.list():

```
<g:select
        optionKey="id" optionValue="name" 
        name="country.nameid="country.name" from="${Country.list()}"
        onchange="${remoteFunction(
        controller:'country',
        action:'ajaxGetCities',
        params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',
        onComplete:'updateCity(e)')}"
></g:select>
```

Any ideas as to why this code is not working?

Comment: It looks like that grails can't locate your class `Country` and try to resolve it as an instance variable. Do you have modified the code of the tutorial - may be put the `Country` class into a package or misspelled it? Did `Country.list()` works within the `CountryController`?

Comment: This is the path to the gsp page. http://localhost:8080/ajaxSelects/country/ajax

Comment: I am only working out of one package for the entire project. Is there anything I need to put in the gsp page to make sure I can access the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either need to do a page import:

```
    <%@ page import="com.yourpackage.Country" %>
```

or use the full path for the list

```
    from="${com.yourpackage.Country.list()}"
```

You also have mistyped here

```
    name="country.nameid="country.name"
```

Should be

```
    name="country.name" id="country.name"
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the answer!